# How many java files are using string value from String xml

Tags: android, eclipse

I am reading one android project in Eclipse. There is one String value in String xml file.

```
 <string name="emoji_keyboard">Emoji</string>
```

I want to know how many files are using this value. Any idea?

Comment: There's always the fun way of telling-  delete the line and see where the errors are.

Comment: @GabeSechan's comment should be a top rated answer.

Comment: Actually i found the solution. Thanks to @GabeSechan. I delete the string and Build my project. REVEALS ALL SECRETS..;)

Comment: Yes that was a very nice answer. Serious!

Answer (score 1):

You could search for - R.string.emoji_keyboard.

Comment: Ok. How, in Eclipse, all files can be searched at once? I only know how to do it one by one.